# Selecting Multiple Options and Values from a Single Drop Down Box

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a form with multiple drop down options.

I stripped everything down to three questions in the form below, to illustrate my issue.

I have tried this code (and a few variations):

```js
function update_variables(el, standard_val, var_list) {
  standard_val.value = var_list[el.getElementsByTagName('option')[el.selectedIndex].value];
}

var select2 = document.getElementById('think_question'),
  hidden_answer = document.getElementsByName('thought_goes_here')[0];

var why_options = {
  'yes': '',
  'no': 'Well, you tried.'
};

select2.addEventListener('change', function() {
  update_variables(select2, hidden_answer, why_options);
});

var sel_group_control = document.getElementById('follower_question');
var sel_free_will = document.getElementById('think_question');


sel_group_control.addEventListener('change', answer_bypass);

function answer_bypass() {
  var user_choice = sel_group_control.value;
  if (user_choice === 'no') {
    sel_free_will.selectedIndex = 2;
    sel_free_will.style.backgroundColor = "#D3D3D3";
    sel_free_will.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Life Decisions</h2>
<form>
  Be exactly like everone else?
  <select id='follower_question'>
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
  </select>
  <br> Think for yourself?
  <select id='think_question'>
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
  </select>
  <br> Original thought:<input name="thought_goes_here" size="50" value="" id="your_thoughts">
</form>
```

If question 2 is set to 'no' then the answer to question 3 is known and filled in with a response.  If question 1 is 'no' then question 2 should be set to 'no' and read-only.  I expected question 3 to be updated automatically too when choosing 'no' in response to question 1 but that function seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register an event to trigger the second select change.

Like so:

```js
function answer_bypass() {
  var user_choice = sel_group_control.value;
  if (user_choice === 'no') {
    sel_free_will.selectedIndex = 2;
    sel_free_will.style.backgroundColor = "#D3D3D3";
    sel_free_will.disabled = true;

    // Create a new 'change' event
    var event = new Event('change');

    // Dispatch it.
    select2.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```